# Excel Mortgage Amortization Schedule w/ large extra principal payment calculation

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

I have been using a Mortgage Amortization Schedule to figure out my loan payments: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/mortgage-amortization-schedule-TC001056620.aspx

One thing that it is missing is the option to make large principal payments and have it calculate the remaining payments minus that large payment off of the principal amount.

Does anyone know what changes need to be made to do this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this add-on, but what values do you currently feed into it? I think you could do a spreadsheet suiting your needs without this add-on. Can you perhaps give an example of what you input and what you expect to get?

Comment: So, input the Loan Principal amount, interest rate and loan period in years. Then it calculates all my payments, interest, etc. But it doesn't take into account if I want to make a large payment to pay down my principal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this little customized "application" in excel. You only have to make a few changes and change the number of rows for the number of years of payments:

[image]

In this example, I used a Principal amount of $ 2,000,000, rate of 11% and Period of 20 years with equal installments.

The interest charges for each year and the payment is displayed.

In the first line, there are specific formulas:

E2: `=$B$2`

F2: `=E2*$B$3`

G2: `=-PMT($B$3,$B$4-D2+1,E2,0,0)` (This is the 'meat' of the application)

H2: `=E2+F2-G2`

The second row:

E2: `=H2`

F2: `=E3*$B$3`

G2: `=-PMT($B$3,$B$4-D3+1,E3,0,0)`

H2: `=E3+F3-G3`

At this stage, you can drag the 4 formulas down till the last year of payment.

You can of course manually put a value in the column `Payment` and the interest and subsequent payments will immediately be recalculated. I think this is what you were looking for. If the number of periods of payments (years) changes, then this cannot help you unless it is revised completely (have to take into account payments already made and charges accrued already, potential penalties and so on).

You can get a copy of the workbook in the picture through [this link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23298677/Mortgage.xlsx) and toy a bit with it I guess.

---

### The `PMT` formula:

It takes 3 to 5 parameters:

**1. The interest rate for the period.**

Since we're having 11% for 1 year, leave it as such. If the payment was on a monthly basis, you could change it to `Int/12`. Of course, the number of periods will change. I would advise only changing the interest rate to a monthly interest rate and re-calculate a more appropriate loan period (for monthly installment, change 11% to `=0.11/12` and change the period to `=20*12`)

**2. The number of period until the loan is fully repaid.**

This is 20 in the example. If you have monthly payments, you will need to change this to ``20*12` and change the interest rate accordingly as mentioned above. It won't anymore be strictly 'years' then, but periods until full repayment of loan.

**3. The present value of the loan.**

This is the loan you took. Shouldn't be difficult. Now in the spreadsheet, I made this value dynamic so that it changes each time the net balance changes, hence can accommodate a change in payment and still recalculate the subsequent interests and payments.

**4. Fair value of loan (optional, defaults to `0`).**

Put a value there if the loan at the end has a fair value. Usually, you pay the totality of the loan by the end of the periods, so it'll be zero, but if for example, after 2 years, the loan value has to be $100,000, put `100000` here.

**5. Type of loan (optional, defaults to `0`).**

There are two types of loans the `pmt` formula recognises:

1. Loans where payments are made at the beginning of the month (value 1),
2. Loans where payments are made at the end of the month (value 0).

This should be pretty straightforward to understand.

Let me know if you have any questions :)

Comment: This is perfect! One issue I am having. I set it to $130,000, 3% and 30 years. After the 5th year things start to get strange. Payment says 300,000 and then 10,215 all the years after that. Doesn't seem like the calculation is correct...

Comment: @hubbas Oh haha, I left one amount in there in cell G6. Take cell G5, copy and paste it over G6. Sorry about that, I was testing 'forced' payments into the sheet. Let me know how it works :)

Comment: @hubbas Awesome! ^^